# Php procedure without a nested query, make it useful code

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

does anyone know how to make this procedure with just one query instead of nested query, Basically I'm trying to get sub categories inside main category in a dropdown menu. I've been thiking about it for to long, but for now I'm just using this nested loop cause i can't figure out another way.
Thanks !

```
    <ul role=menu>
    <?php 
        $statement = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
        $statement->execute();
        while($category = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
    ?>
       <li><a href='<?php echo '/'.urlencode($category['name']);?>.html'><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
          <ul>
          <?php 
            $stmt = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM area WHERE belong_to_category = :category_name");
            $stmt->execute(array(':category_name' => $category['name']));
            while($sub_category = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
          ?>
             <li role="menuitem"><a href='<?php echo '/'.urlencode($sub_category['name']);?>.html'><?php echo $sub_category['name'];?></a>
          <?php 
            }
          ?>        
          </ul>
       </li>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>      
    </ul>
```

Comment: where's the `category_id` of table `area` which belongs to table `category`? just use a simple join with it

Comment: @Ghost, its not that simple, obviously i would use inner joins, but i will have no control of who is the parent and who is the sub category. they just don't fit here, idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a simple JOIN in your query statement in conjunction into using PDO fetch [`PDO::FETCH_GROUP`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) as stated here.

In turn, you'll get the category as keys, then the corresponding values are the sub categories.

You haven't posted any db schema so I'll just give an example of joining them thru the keys.

Basic idea:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT category.name AS category_name, area.name AS area_name FROM category
    JOIN area ON area.category_id = category.id
'; // just a simple join

$statement = $database->prepare($sql);
$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// use the `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` flag
// this turns the fetched data into a grouped one

// ul
foreach($data as $category => $sub_categories) {
    // li
    echo $category; // category name
        // ol

        foreach($sub_categories as $s) {
            // li
            echo $s['area_name']; // the area name
            // close li
        }
        // close ol
    // li close
}
// ul close

// Just fetch the necessary depth, this is just an idea
```

Edit. Another way would just to build up the array manually. Still the same query statement but without using the `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`.

Along these lines:

```
$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // no fetch group
$final_data = array();
foreach($data as $values) {
    $final_data[$values['category_name']][] = $values['area_name'];
    // assign category as key, push into the array container the area name
}

// then get going on building your desired html markup using the manually grouped `$final_data` below
```

Comment: Ghost, this is the exact answer I was looking for, thank you very much ! , Just one more question , is it possible to add something to the query to make the same effect as FETCH_GROUP ?, without FETCH_GROUP OF PDO?

Comment: @gdf if i'd guess you could use group concat function in mysql of course you'd still have that join, but you could do that without the `FETCH_GROUP` flag, you'll have to `explode()` by `,` instead

Comment: how do i make that group_concat, sorry for troubling you, I just had that problem for long time

Comment: @gdf just rewrite the query by adding the function in it, along these lines, just adjust accordingly `SELECT area.name AS area_name, GROUP_CONCAT(category.name) AS category_names FROM area
JOIN category ON area_category.id = category.id`

Comment: you'll just have to `explode` the `category_names` then a simple `foreach` under that rendering along with the markup should work